# Matching an expression in python regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match a coordinate with a python string regex, but I'm not getting a result. I was to see if the input is a valid coordinate definition but I'm not getting the correct match using the code below. Can someone tell me what's wrong?

```
def coordinate(coord):
     a = re.compile("^(([0-9]+), ([0-9]+))$")
     b = a.match(coord)
     if b:
         return True
     return False
```

Currently, it's returning false even if I pass in `(3, 4)` which is a valid coordinate.

Comment: For a start, you want `b = a.match(coord)`, not `b = re.match(coord)`.

Comment: You need to escape some of the parentheses in the regex string.  You have some parens in there and you mean literal parens but they will be interpreted as a capture group.

Comment: @TimPeters but then I'd expect a `TypeError` because of incorrect arguments... So I'm really not sure if we're dealing with the actual code here...

Comment: how do I escape the parens? I typed it wrong here, I used a.match in my program. Fixed.

Comment: If you're doing nothing more than returning True/False, then you can just do `return bool(a.match(coord))` instead... However, it wouldn't hurt that much to return the match object anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
from re import match
def coordinate(coord):   
    return bool(match("\s*\(\s*-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*,\s*-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*\)\s*$", coord))
```

It is also quite powerful, having the ability to handle negative numbers, fractions, and an optional space between the numbers.

Below is a breakdown of the Regex pattern:

```
\s*         # Zero or more whitespace characters
\(          # An opening parenthesis
\s*         # Zero or more whitespace characters
-?          # An optional hyphen (for negative numbers)
\d+         # One or more digits
(?:\.\d+)?  # An optional period followed by one or more digits (for fractions)
\s*         # Zero or more whitespace characters
,           # A comma
\s*         # Zero or more whitespace characters
-?          # An optional hyphen (for negative numbers)
\d+         # One or more digits
(?:\.\d+)?  # An optional period followed by one or more digits (for fractions)
\s*         # Zero or more whitespace characters
\)          # A closing parenthesis
\s*         # Zero or more whitespace characters
$           # End of the string
```

Comment: Maybe an optional space would be better. Great explanation!

Comment: `\s?` seems odd to me - it matches one space, or one tab, or one newline, or any other single whitespace character, but not two spaces.  Matching tabs but not multiple spaces feels inconsistent. If I were composing the regex, I would probably choose either `\040?` or `\s*`.

Comment: Consider an optional leading and ending space; i.e.: `"\s*\(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?,\s?-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?\)\s*$"`

Comment: Thanks for the tips; I have incorporated them into my post.  When building something complex, it sure does help to have it reviewed by more than just yourself. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the parentheses that you are trying to match. Try using the following:

```
^(\([0-9]+,\s[0-9]+\))$
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you do not properly escape the parenthesis that makes the coordinate syntax. In regex, parenthesis are [special characters used for grouping and capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). You need to escape them this way:

```
>>> a = re.compile("^\(([0-9]+), ([0-9]+)\)$")
>>> a.match("(3, 4)")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000001D91E00>
```